# Sphinx warning "reference target not found" for standard C types

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Sphinx running in the nitpick mode emits warnings like "WARNING: c:type reference target not found: wchar_t" and "WARNING: c:identifier reference target not found: wchar_t" for references to standard C types like `wchar_t`, `FILE` or `va_list`. It complains about all types that aren't just keywords, like `long`, `unsigned int` or `const char *`.

Adding `('c:type', 'wchar_t')` to the `nitpick_ignore` list in `conf.py` solves problem in `` :c:type:`wchar_t` ``, but not in `` :c:texpr:`wchar_t *` `` and, what is more important, not in function declarations:

```
.. c:function:: int foobar(const wchar_t *arg)
```

How can I get rid of these warnings? How do I tell Sphinx that `wchar_t`, `FILE` and `va_list` are C types defined outside my project?

Comment: See the answer here, where they define a nitpick_ignore dict https://github.com/breathe-doc/breathe/issues/696